# Calculating duration using start and end date in Drupal view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to make my view display the duration of each event in the table. My event has a date field storing the start and end dates. Could you please recommend what is the most efficient way to approach it?

I was trying to use views field handler but I don't how to access the date values of my Event content type. My database contains 'field_data_field_duration' table. Should I use it to extract the necessary values?

Comment: google is your friend. [https://www.drupal.org/project/date_duration_formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_duration_formatter)

Answer (score 0):

You could just display both dates as timestamp and in the template or preprocess of your view use this php function : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

No need to add another module for that.